# I want to redirect my site trafic on another port from a subdomain

Tags: server, apache2, virtualhost

I want to redirect my trafic from my subdomain i.e blog.somesite.com to port i.e somesite.com:3000 using Virtual Host. 
My default Virtual Host configuration was:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>        

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/somesite.com/httpdocs/        

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Changes I made:

```
<VirtualHost somesite.com:80>        

            ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
            DocumentRoot /var/www/somesite.com/httpdocs/        

            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost blog.somesite.com:80>
    ServerName  blog.somesite.com
    ServerAlias www.blog.somesite.com

    ProxyPass /  http://somesite.com:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://somesite.com:3000/


</VirtualHost>
```

By doing so my site goes down. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot enter DNS names in "VirtualHost". Try the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>        
        ServerName somesite.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/somesite.com/httpdocs/        

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName blog.somesite.com
    ServerAlias www.blog.somesite.com

    ProxyPass /  http://somesite.com:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://somesite.com:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```